# redirect URL with specific words in the url path to another page

Tags: .htaccess

I have a path in some of my urls that results in an undesirable destination that I dont want users to browse to: i.e: http://mywebsite/mysite/undesirable-path/anything-could-be-here/

When users browse to any page with /undesirable-path/ in the url Id like them to just end up at the home page.

another more complex example would be:

1. http://mywebsite/mysite/undesirable-path/anything-could-be-here/
2. http://mywebsite/yoursite/undesirable-path/anything-could-be-here/

so something like *?/undesirable-path/*? - anything before and anything after.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 
www.mysite.com/baddir/(.*) 
www.mysite.com/$1
```